# Missing package statement: 'com.VRCoreSoftware.testapp4'

Tags: java, android, android-intent, import, package

I'm trying to begin learning the ropes of programming Android applications, and so I am following the Android developer tutorials. I'm currently working on the "Starting Another Activity" section, and have followed the sample exactly, with the exception of the app name. When I add the class code for the second activity to be called when a button is clicked, I get the following error: Missing package statement: 'com.VRCoreSoftware.testapp4'

All of the relevant pieces of code (as far as I am aware of), are shown below:

Main Activity.java:
The only error showing here is that it does not recognize DisplayMessageActivity.class
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);

```
package com.VRCoreSoftware.testapp4;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
// import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.VRCoreSoftware.testapp4.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java
There are many errors, with the source (I'm assuming) being the apparent failed import.

```
import com.VRCoreSoftware.testapp4.MainActivity;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends MainActivity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

     // Create the text view
     TextView textView = new TextView(this);
     textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

From the AndroidManifest.xml file:
The only error here is that it does not recognize 'DisplayMessageActivity' in the line:
android:name="com.VRCoreSoftware.testapp4.DisplayMessageActivity"

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.VRCoreSoftware.testapp4.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.VRCoreSoftware.testapp4.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.VRCoreSoftware.testapp4.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

I am currently using Android Studio to write and compile this code.
I would greatly appreciate any and all help on this matter.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems DisplayMessageActivity isn't in the same package as MainActivity, which also means it's not in `com.VRCoreSoftware.testapp4`, making the manifest wrong. Move it to the correct package and you're good to go.